Downloading Maven dependencies from private repositories
I have a microservices project with Spring Boot that shares utilities and entities and repositories in common, so as not to replicate the code in each service. I decided to create a library that I called common, which includes everything that is common to each service. I've deployed it on the GitLab package registry, and it's working fine, even the deployment. The problem is when I need to import this dependence into other projects. When I run the command mvn install everything's fine except that when I import a class from my package it tells me that the class doesn't exist.
The aim is that when I install my project's dependencies, it searches my GitLab registry and if it doesn't find anything, it searches the Maven Central repository Here's my pom.xml file
<repositories>
    <!-- Ton repository GitLab -->
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>my_url_gitlab_package_registry</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <!-- Maven Central comme fallback -->
    <repository>
        <id>maven-central</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

and in the dependencies I add this:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.packages</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

I've also updated my settings.xml to allow authentication with GitLab, which works fine. I've added a mirror to my settings.xml so that it can look in the GitLab.
<mirror>
  <id>gitlab-maven</id>
  <name>GitLab proxy of central repo</name>
  <url>my_url_gitlab_package_registry</url>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>

When I modify the pom.xml and add my dependency and then I run mvn install it ends with success, except that my dependency is not part of the dependency install I even checked in the .m2\repository directory and when I try an individual install through the command
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:get -Dartifact=com.packages:common:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -DrepoUrl=my_url_gitlab_package_registry -DrepositoryId=gitlab-maven

I get this error
Error resolving version for plugin '.bjft:package' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]

This means that it's trying to find my package in the maven-central repository even though my package is in the GitLab package registry. I don't know where I've gone wrong.

Check Dependency Scope: Ensure that the scope of your dependency is set correctly. By default, it should be compile, but if it's set to provided, runtime, or test, it might not be available during runtime. Here's how it should look in your pom.xml:

com.packages
common
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
compile 

then run mvn clean install

Do you provide the necessary credentials for accessing the private repo? You need to define those in settings.xml:   <servers><server><id>gitlab-maven</id><username>xxx</username><password>xxx</password></server></servers>. I don't think you need to include a mirror in settings.xml because pom.xml already defines the repository.

The settings.xml file has been properly configured. The connection with the gitlab package registry is working normally.
